# Linear dependent functions

Tags: linear-algebra

V is a linear space of all functions $\ \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ and $\ f,g,h \in V $

$\ f(x) = x\cos x $ , $\ g(x) = \cos x $, $\ h(x) = \sin x $

Need to see if those functions are dependent.

$\ 0 = \alpha_1 x\cos x + \alpha_2\cos x + \alpha_3 \sin x $

lets say $\ t= \cos x , s = \sin x $

$\ \alpha_1 x t + \alpha_2 t + \alpha_3 s $ = 0

$\ t(\alpha_1x + \alpha_2) + s \alpha_3 = 0 $

Not sure how do i go on from here? and I haven't been taught the Wronskian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just working out Alan's hint:
$$\ 0 \equiv \alpha_1 x\cos x + \alpha_2\cos x + \alpha_3 \sin x$$
Set

- $x= 0 \Rightarrow \alpha_2 = 0$
- $x= \pi \stackrel{\alpha_2 = 0}{\Rightarrow} -\alpha_1 \pi = 0 \Rightarrow\alpha_1 = 0$
- $x=\frac{\pi}{2}\stackrel{\alpha_1=0,\alpha_2 = 0}{\Rightarrow}\alpha_3 = 0$

It follows that the three functions are linearly independent, as the coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ have to be zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately i still can't seem to grasp the idea behind it.  Basically can I just pick any random value of x and then just see what happen to the coefficients ? Not sure what did Alan mean by "show they are inconsistent"

Comment: We want to show that the three vectors - here the three given functions - are linearly independent. This means we need to consider linear combinations of these three functions that produce the zero-FUNCTION:
$\ 0 \equiv \alpha_1 x\cos x + \alpha_2\cos x + \alpha_3 \sin x$. This in turn means these coefficients produce for any $x$ always the value zero. If we succeed in showing that this is only possible when all the coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ are equal to zero, then we are done. So, we pick some specific $x$ and check what consequences this has for the coefficients.

Comment: @Yarden: The word "inconsistent" is maybe a bit misleading. One may use it if you wanted to prove the independence of the three functions by contradiction. In this case you would assume a non-trivial linear combination $\ 0 \equiv \alpha_1 x\cos x + \alpha_2\cos x + \alpha_3 \sin x$ with at least one of the coefficients to be non-zero. Then, picking some specific values for $x$ would show that the equations obtained for the coefficients would be "inconsistent" with this assumption.

Comment: Okay.. I think I'm starting to get it. Another question, is I need to choose n different values for x where n = no' of functions , am I correct? I mean the end goal is to create new equations with the coefficients?

Comment: Yes. To show the independence of $n$ real functions $f_1(x),\ldots , f_n(x)$ directly using linear combinations, you set up the general equation to produce the zero-function: $0 \equiv \alpha_1 f_1(x) + \cdots +\alpha_n f_n(x)$. Then you choose $n$ different $x$-values in the common domain of these functions. That way you obtain an $n\times n$ linear system for the coefficients $\alpha_1 \cdots ,\alpha_n $. Here, choosing the $x$-values wisely can help simplify this system. If you can show that this system has only the trivial solution $\alpha_1 =\cdots  = \alpha_n = 0$, then you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot trancelocation!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint.   If your first equation is true, it is true for all values of x.  Try specific values of x, that will give you multiple equations that are linear in your coefficients.   Show they are inconsistent.